# Triggering a svg animation with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-waypoints, svg-animate

I have a .svg file that animates a circle to move using the animateMotion. The problem is that I load the file with jquery at the bottom of my page. By the time the user has scrolled down, the animation has already played. I'm using the waypoints jquery plugin which runs a function when a div is in the viewport. I would love to use this to trigger the animateMotion within the .svg.

Thoughts and ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply reload the file when it comes up? That would probably run the animateMotion automatically because it will assume this is the initial loading of the file.

Comment: I did try that. It runs into issues with slow internet connections. Sometimes part of the svg doesn't show when run that way.

So, inside the waypoints function, I added this:
    $("#greystage").load('svg/greyslide.svg',function(response){
 
            $(this).addClass("svgLoaded");
        if(!response){

        }
    });